# Glue crawler reports 0 tables updated even though Athena query returns data for new partition

Tags: aws-glue

I have a Glue crawler running every night on a bucket in S3 partitioned on year, month and day.

It seems to be working because when querying the database for the latest partition it returns rows.

But in the Glue console it says 0 Tables updated.

How can this be?

Comment: Can you verify if version is modified for table in the glue catalog after crawler run completed ?

Comment: The table version hasn't updated. But I wouldn't expected it since no new columns are created in between runs.

Comment: What does your cloud watch logs says? Is it saying no new files/partitions located? If the table version is not updated then your latest partition should not be present in the results

Comment: Actually, the logs says "Classification complete, writing results to database..." so I guess it should be fine. Still don't understand why it says 0 tables updated in the Glue console.